# How to detect sprite's edges are close. Cocos 2d for ios

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, sprite

I am developing a jig-so puzzle like app using cocos2d. I have put some sprites into the scene and particular two sprites are matching. If i have put rectangle shaped sprites, i can determine their positions. If they are close enough, therefore re arrange two of them.

```
 float distanceFromCorrectPos = ccpDistance(selectedSprite.position, sda.position);

    if( distanceFromCorrectPos <= 70  ){

        if(selectedSprite == [movableSprites objectAtIndex:0]){
            [selectedSprite  setPosition:ccp(sda.position.x+75, sda.position.y)];

        }
    }
```

My problem is if i using asymmetric images for sprites. How can i detect matching sprites are close enough.

Comment: there is a lot of question here and themes in the internet about pixel perfect collision

Comment: Are your puzzle pieces unique shaped (in fact they are supposed to be)? If they are, they should have only one place to match, so you can check if they are placed that place on the board, instead of detecting collision.